# Next.js not showing data on page/component after getting props from getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

I'm getting data from the server with `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const packageIdentifier = context.params.packageIdentifier;
  const data = await getReviewsData(packageIdentifier);

  return {
    props: {
      response: {
        packageIdentifier,
        data,
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Then i'm trying to load the data into a component in my page, the data appears but not showing when the page is rendered:

```
export default function ReviewsPage({ response }) {
  // DATA IS PRINTED TO CONSOLE AND WORKING FINE
  console.log(`Reviews Data: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
  
  const { data, setData } = useState(response.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(response.data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Box>
        { data && <Reviews reviews={data} /> }
        { !data && <div>There are no reviews to display.</div> }
      </Box>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

The render (return) is sending `'There are no reviews to display'`. Which means that `data` is empty for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `const [ data, setData ]` instead of `const { data, setData }`

Comment: I knew that his is a stupid syntax problem! :) Thank you very much...